# How to use @app_commands.describe in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have been working on creating a application command in discord.py and got a test command working but could not find any documentation on adding arguments to them. I found a few code snippets showing the @app_commands.describe function being used but that is all.

I tried using num1 and num2 with descriptions under the @app_commands.describe function but they arent showing up as variables.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) provides a very clear answer.

> [`@app_commands.description`] Describes the given parameters by their name using the key of the keyword argument as the name

```
@app_commands.command(description='Bans a member')
@app_commands.describe(member='the member to ban')
async def ban(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Banned {member}')
```

The `member` paramter in `app_commands.describe` is the same parameter `member` in the command definition.